# subprocess call of sed command giving error

Tags: python, regex, sed, subprocess

I have a text file which contains the following line

```
PIXEL_SCALE      1.0            # size of pixel in arc
```

To replace 1.0 in it with 0.3,
I tried to use sed via subprocess.call from python script.
Following sed regex command works perfectly from shell.

```
sed -i 's/^\(PIXEL_SCALE\s*\)\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\)/\10.3/' filename.txt
```

But the equivalent subprocess.call command gives me the following error.

```
subprocess.call(['sed','-i',"'s/^\(PIXEL_SCALE\s*\)\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\)/\10.3/'",'filename.txt'])

sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
```

I tried converting the string to raw string by prefixing string with r and also tried .encode("UTF-8"). But they didn't have any effect.
What could be going wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: try subprocess.Popen("sed -i 's/^\(PIXEL_SCALE\s*\)\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\)/\10.3/' filename.txt",shell=True")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'` quotes are delimiters used by the shell. As you do not use a shell, you don't need them around your regular expression:

```
subprocess.call(['sed','-i',r"s/^\(PIXEL_SCALE\s*\)\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\)/\10.3/",'filename.txt'])
#                           ^^                                                             ^
```

In addition, I used a [*raw string*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) (`r"...."`) to prevent interpretation of the backslash-escaped sequences by python.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I had tried both removing the quotes as well as adding r separately. but didn't try both together. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
subprocess.call("sed -i 's/^\(PIXEL_SCALE\s*\)\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\)/\10.3/' filename.txt", shell=True)
```

that works

Comment: Thanks. But to make it work i also had to suffix the string with an r to prevent python from escaping the \s in it.

Comment: Adding `shell=True`  fixes it by adding yet another  process between you and your data. A better fix is to  understand what's going on, and remove the shell from complicating things. A better fix still would be to perform this simple replacement in Python itself, which is well equipped for the task.

Answer (score 0):

```
's/(PIXEL_SCALE\s*)[0-9]+[0-9]+/\10.3/'
```

Comment: Could you includes words in your anwser? That might make it clearer.