# Call sed via subprocess

Tags: python, sed

I need to call Sed via Python. I tried the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522639/subprocess-call-of-sed-command-giving-error) question, however it doesn't work.

My code is (yes the file doesn't have an extension, it works when using putty):

```
filename = '/home/user1/file'
subprocess.call(["sed","-i",r"$'s/[][]//g;s/,/\\\n/g'",filename])
```

Can someone see what is going wrong? The script executes, but just skips the subprocess call.

---

Ok so I tried it using the Python re module this is my code:

```
filename = '/home/user/file'
filenametemp = '/home/user/temp'
file = open(filename, "r")
temp = open(filenametemp,"w+")
text = file.read()

text = re.sub(r'\[|\]',r'',text)
text = re.sub(r',',r'\n', text)
print text

temp.write(text)

header_row=['H1','H2','H3'] 
data = pd.read_csv(filenametemp, sep= ';',skipinitialspace=1, names=header_row)
```

The file "temp" is now in the correct layout, however Pandas creates an empty dataframe when opening this file.
However if I comment out:

```
 #temp = open(filenametemp,"w+")
 #temp.write(text)
```

And run the script again all the data is loaded correctly in a dataframe.

Can somebody explain why this is happening and has an solution for this?

---

It turned out that I had to close the file before it can be used. So although it is not done with a subprocess call to sed this returned the correct solution:

```
filename = '/home/user/file'
filenametemp = '/home/user/temp'
file = open(filename, "r")
temp = open(filenametemp,"w+")
text = file.read()

text = re.sub(r'\[|\]',r'',text)
text = re.sub(r',',r'\n', text)
print text

temp.write(text)
temp.close()

header_row=['H1','H2','H3'] 
data = pd.read_csv(filenametemp, sep= ';',skipinitialspace=1, names=header_row)
```

Comment: Did you miss the bit about not needing the single quotes when run this way because you aren't using a shell? If you need the escape sequences turned into literal characters (and you probably don't) then I think not using a raw string will do that for you if you don't escape them from python.

Comment: "just skips the subprocess call" - don't make wild assumptions. clearly that's not the case.

Comment: Just a thought, but why are you using `sed` when you have Python?

Comment: I use sed because I have a working solution for this. If you have another solution for within Python I want to try this as well. However below Rob mentioned the re module but from the documentation I cannot find out how this works.

Comment: Please don't edit the question to provide an answer. Instead, post your own answer (and accept it if you like; that way, your question will no longer come up as unresolved).

Comment: @tripleee, I didn't answer the original question. I only provided another solution which made it work for me. My original question was running sed through a subprocess call, therefore I didn't write it in an anwser. Should I post it in an anwser still?

Answer (score 4):

1) "*I need to call Sed via Python*". I don't think that you really need that. A Python program, using the `re` module, can do everything that `sed` can do, and more.

2) "*The script executes, but just skips the subprocess call.*" I don't think that's accurate, either. It seems much more likely that `subprocess.call` actually *is* invoked, and that `sed` runs, but that the syntax error in the `sed` command prevents `sed` from completing its duty.

3) Your string had several extra characters in it. It didn't need `$`, `'`, or quite so many `\`. Try this:

```
import subprocess
filename = '/tmp/file'
subprocess.call(["sed","-i",r"s/[][]//g;s/,/\n/g",filename])
```

Here is `/tmp/file` before:

```
Hello[] This Is[] A Test, this is just a test, you[] know?
```

and after:

```
Hello This Is A Test
 this is just a test
 you know?
```

Comment: Hi Rob I tried your solution however it doesn't change anything to the file either. Same as before. As for point 1 I don't need to do it in Sed but I looked at the re module and I from the documentation I cannot find out how this works.